# Deplhi Import Component - Type Library vs ActiveX

Tags: delphi, com, activex

I am trying to use the "Microsoft Terminal Services Active Client" in Delphi. I see that I can create the COM *.tlb file either via "*Import ActiveX control*" or "*Import Type Library*". They both seem to give the same *.tlb source file.

Is there a difference between the two approaches. (Long time Delphi user, but new to COM).

Answer (score 1):

Delphi Help System says:

"The Import Type Library dialog box displays the type libraries registered on your system so you can add them to your projects. If the registered type libraries contain creatable CoClasses, this dialog allows you to install components representing them on the component palette. You can generate declarations in a .pas file that let you use these types as though they were native objects."

"The Import ActiveX Control dialog displays the ActiveX controls registered on your system so you can add them to your projects. You can declare the controls in source files so that you can use any of these controls as though it were a native object."

Import ActiveX Control is only from controls, Type library is for libraries (no visual ones) but if they exposes visual controls, they are also installed into you IDE.

Comment: I did read the help file. But, that didn't clear my confusion. "Terminal Services Client" is available in both places. Are you saying that if imported as type library then it cannot be visual ?

Comment: No, I'm saying "Import type library" is for non visual library classes, BUT, if theses classes define visual controls, they will installed :)  
The main difference is that in Import ActiveX in only for visual controls.