# vb6 dll In Delphi

Tags: delphi, vb6

I have written a VB6 dll with this code

```
Public Function RegGetStr(ByRef FullLocation_Name As String) As String
   Dim oReg As Object
    Set oReg = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    RegGetStr = oReg.RegRead(FullLocation_Name, "REG_SZ")

    Set oReg = Nothing
End Function
```

In Delphi I have library working

```
type
          TRegGetStr = Function(Const FullLocation_Name: String): String; StdCall;
    var
     aRegGetStr: TRegGetStr;
```

and

```
 @aRegGetStr := Windows.GetProcAddress(LibHandle, 'RegGetStr');
```

I have a crash
Is it because of the types of strings I'm using? or something else?

Comment: Yes, that code cannot be consumed by your Delphi module because the string type is not valid for interop.

Comment: Of course you could just read the registry from your Delphi code. You really should stop writing new code in VB6. Did you miss the memo?

Comment: IIRC, In VB6, you interop strings with PAnsiChar, so it probably should be something like: `TRegGetStr = procedure(FullLocation_Name: PAnsiChar; Result: PAnsiChar) stdcall;` and on the VB side: `Public Function RegGetStr(ByVal FullLocation_Name As String, ByVal Result As String)`, but I am not fully sure. You should try it though. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.objectpascal/P-eMVQJ-YI0).

Comment: Isn't VB targeted to support ActiveX, just like VBA? perhaps COM BSTR aka Delphi WideString can be used ? or OleString ?

Comment: Most examples I have seen are DLLs written in C and used byVB6. This: 'void __export CALLBACK GetDiskInfo (char *cDrive, char *szVolumeName,  unsigned long *ulFreeSpace)` is converted as `Declare Sub getdiskinfo Lib "c:\somepath\diskinfo.dll" (ByVal mydrive As String, ByVal myvolume As String, free As Long)`. The other way around should be similar.

Comment: The Delphi equivalent would be: `procedure GetDiskInfo(cDrive, szVolumeName: PAnsiChar; var ulFreeSpace: Longword); stdcall;`. I assume all should be 'stdcall', but I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/kb/118643) might help. Passing between C and VB is the same as passing between Delphi and VB. Just know that `char *` equates to `PAnsiChar`. There is a special type, `hlstr` for VB6 strings as return type. I don't quite know how to translate that yet. Return types of different languages are always a problem. I would rather use an extra var parameter (`ByRef Result As String`, in VB6), and a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asked about calling a VB DLL from Delphi.
VB6, out of the box, creates ActiveX dll's (created as an ActiveX DLL project)
  [How can I create a standard DLL in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253976/how-can-i-create-a-standard-dll-in-vb6)  Look at the answer there describing ActiveX DLL.

While you can create standard DLL's in VB6 you have to go spelunking.  It does not support that out of the box and is not recommended.

You would consume that VB ActiveX DLL just as you would any ActiveX dll in Delphi.
 [Deplhi Import Component - Type Library vs ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064693/deplhi-import-component-type-library-vs-activex)

=====

IF, on the other hand, you are trying to call an external DLL (e.g. written in Delphi) **FROM** a VB application, you would create the Delphi function with pAnsiChar  parameters for strings.  Ex: in MyDelProcs.dll:

```
procedure MyDelProc(pStr1: pAnsiChar, MyInt: integer);stdcall;
  .......................
exports
  MyDelProc;
```

On the VB side you would then declare the procedure as

Declare Sub MyDelProc Lib "MyDelProcs.dll" (ByVal sStr1 as String, MyLong As Long)

Then call the procedure with

```
   Call MyDelProc(sStr1, MyLong)
```

Some notes:

1. sStr1 is Unicode internal to VB, but on the call is converted to AnsiString.  The ansistring has a chr(0) added to the end and moved to a buffer which is the length of the ansistring plus the chr(0).
2. Take care with other parameter types.  Default Integer in VB is 2 bytes, default integer in Delphi is 4, which is equivalent to a Long type in VB.
3. If your Delphi function needs to know the length, pass it as another (long/integer) parameter.
4. The string buffer is fixed in size.  If you are returning a string of longer length then either pad the original string with enough room, or pass a longer dummy string with enough length for the return.
5. Upon return the string is treated as ansistring.  It will be converted back to Unicode to be placed into a VB internal string.

Comment: SO won't let me add a comment to the question, so I'll add a comment here.  VB strings are Unicode under the hood, but are passed externally as ansistring.  When calling external DLL's *from* VB, that is the case.  The calls Rudy describes are correct in that case.   When creating DLL's with VB, to be called from Delphi, things are different.  You can create ActiveX interfaces that run either in process or out-of-process ActiveX (as EXE).  There are some unsupported methods for calling into VB as straight DLL that I don't recommend, but they involve starting up the VB piece for initialization.

Comment: Who is the fool that brought up ActiveX, I'm making a VB6 *.DLL, nothing else, please read the question correctly, Rudy Velthuis thanks for your comment, I never thought to use string pointers but that may be better to be received as PChar in Delphi I think. I just want to get the communication correct between Delphi and VB6. I have InteropFormToolsInstaller installed on VB6 but what does that change. The String of Delphi should collect a VB ansi string.

Comment: Dan Barcaly thanks I was hopping to make Delphi drop the dll from a resource in Delphi and load library to make the project portable. The dll feature seemed so easy to use in VB6.

Comment: I was wandering if  Rudy Velthuis idea and use memory allocated from Delphi and not the dll would be a way out.

Comment: Who is the fool that brought up ActiveX?  Microsoft.  I pointed that out here.  If that offends you, sorry, just pointing out facts.  Standard DLL's are easy to consume in VB6, true enough.  I do it all the time.  But I understood your question as consuming a VB6 created DLL with a Delphi application.  That is entirely different, and you need to speak ActiveX OR you need to look into unsupported/undocumented methods for creating the DLL.  There are (or were, I haven't looked lately) 3rd party tools to expose VB6 functions as DLL's.  I have not used those, only have heard of them.

Comment: The comments Rudy was making regard calling an external (Delphi/C etc) DLL *from* VB.  In those cases strings are converted to ansistring, then exposed as a "buffer".  You can get cute and get to the string parameters, and even change length, if you want to make undocumented calls but it's supposed to work as Rudy said.. a buffer of pAnsiChar.  Still, that is calling Delphi from VB, not the reverse.

Comment: Calling into VB without ActiveX can be done, sort of.  The "proper" <cough> way to do it is to create a VB app, expose functions with callbacks, then call your Delphi/C/etc code, which can callback into VB.  Very ugly.  I've only done that as play.  The VB app has to be the "top level app" for that.  All of these limitations (using ActiveX, etc) are controlled by the need for VB to initialize a pot full of internal pieces.  Let me ask a more fundamental question:  What is it that you need to do in VB6 for your Delphi app??  Knowing the objective might allow us to come up with some solution.

Comment: I found the answer: - dll's in general are no good at allocating memory from the application's stack. So allocate the strings larger than you need before hand in an array block, Send it as a PChar of the array. In VB6 use ByRef like you use var as a pointer in Delphi and Delphi has allocated the memory for the dll. PAnsiChar or similar is not available in vb6.

Comment: That answer is correct, but only when you are calling a non-vb DLL from VB.  The buffer size will be the size of the string plus one.  When calling a DLL with strings, VB adds a chr(0) to the end just to be "helpful".  The string is converted to ANSI before calling so the buffer sizing is based on the string character length, not the internal memory length in VB.